# Android 2D panoramic video player

Tags: android, video, 360-panorama, 360-panorama-viewer

I am working in iOS and Android app that play 2D Panoramic video player.

We find an [Open Source iOS 2D Panorama Video Player app](https://github.com/hanton/HTY360Player)

But we can't find any open source library for android.
Please suggest any open source android 2D video player to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is 3 months old by now, you probably found it (or something else) yourself.

However, as other people might still be searching for it: [gvr-android-sdk](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview) is Google's SDK for various VR-usages. Take a look at the *simplevideowidget*-sample included in the SDK.

There is also an [iOS-Version](https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/vr-view) available.